# What id basic datatype to store big number in java?

Tags: java

I want to store a very big number of range 15477096172227810860 approximate. This number is store in a String and when i am converting it into Long its giving me NumberFormatException. I think long does not sport that much lengthy value. Please give me some solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) can be used for large numbers. It will also be easy to declare from a String.

```
BigInteger num = new BigInteger("15477096172227810860");
```

Note that it's not a "basic datatype" (primitive), so you will have to call methods to get the value or "modify" it. (It's immutable fyi). As mentioned by other answers, the length of the number is limited by the memory available.

Answer (score 2):

A [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) can store an arbitrarily large number (usually the memory available sets the limit).

Answer (score 0):

Best part (and only?) is to use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Though, it depends on what you wnt to do with that number